# How to change the orientation of the x-axis label in an asp.net radar chart?

Tags: asp.net, charts, label, orientation, radar-chart

I have 4 radar charts on my Webpage.
Three out of the four charts have horizontally orientated x axis labels.
One of the charts has its labels orientated towards the centre of the chart.

All charts are created dynamically in the same way. I believe it is occurring because the one chart has a large number of points.

Please see the below image.
[image]

I have the following code setting the orientation of the Xaxis, but this does not work.

```
ca.AxisX.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;
```

The code I have tried so far has not worked. I inserted the following code to see if I could change the orientation of any of the axes, it changes the orientation of the y axis but not the x axis.

```
foreach (Axis axis in chartArea.Axes)
            {
                axis.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None;
                axis.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 50;
                axis.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
                axis.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
                aaxisTextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;

            }
```

How do I make all charts have their x axis labels orientated horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it may be useful to someone else in the future:

```
chart.Series[series1]["CircularLabelsStyle"] = "Horizontal";
```

Other option are `Radial` and `Circular`

Please see the following link for more details about custom attributes.
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456627%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)